# PHP Simple Html Dom parsing a php form

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I have this php page:

```
exercice_submit.php?exerciseId=7
```

Which has several nested div inside

```
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
<div id="content_main">
```

Inside last div there is a form:

```
<form action="/modules/exercice/exercice_submit.php" method="post">
```

I want to cut all the other html tags and keep only what is included inside form.
Can you please help me parse this page?

What I used is PHP Simple HTML DOM and I wrote:

```
    // example of how to use basic selector to retrieve HTML contents
    include('../simple_html_dom.php');
    
    // get DOM from URL or file
    $html = file_get_html('exercice/exercice_submit.php');
    
    echo $html->find("#content_main",0);
    echo $html->outertext
    
    ?>
```

This doesn't seem to work. If you can help me maybe you know a way of changing submit button target to submit to different php than what it is.

Thanks in advance for all potential answers.

Comment: Please post the markup from `$html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not used file_get_html, but you could use file_get_contents to load it into a string then use substr in conjunction with strpos on "<form" and "</form>" to get the form.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

http://www.php.net/file_get_contents